# How to create cloudformation template from SAm project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am trying to convert a SAM project to a cloudformation template in order to call

> cloudformation.createStack()

to create multiple stacks when a lambda is invoked. So far I can upload the SAM project with

> sam build
> sam package

But the size of the S3 is to big and I am getting errors. What are the steps to correctly upload the cloudformation template?

Answer (score 0):

These pre-reqs need to be met before continuing:

1. Install the SAM CLI.
2. Create an Amazon S3 bucket to store the serverless code artifacts that the SAM template generates. At a minimum, you will need permission to put objects into the bucket.
3. The permissions applied to your IAM identity must include iam:ListPolicies.

4.You must have AWS credentials configured either via the AWS CLI or in your shell's environment via the AWS_* environment variables.

5.Git installed.

6.Python 3.x installed.
(Optional) Install Python's virtualenvwrapper.

**Source Link:-** https://www.packetmischief.ca/2020/12/30/converting-from-aws-sam-to-cloudformation/

Comment: I am using nodejs